# Are there substantial consensus results on the political causes and/or consequences of economic inequality in political science?

Tags: economy, reference-request, inequality, political-science

In economics, there are any number of books and articles that provide a broad survey of theoretical and empirical findings on economic inequality. Much of this material is technical, and most of it is, within economics, relatively uncontroversial: construction of inequality indexes and poverty indexes,  longitudinal trends and cross-sectional distribution of measured inequality, anchors in the near-philosophic aspects of social choice theory like the work of Amartya Sen, and so forth. The literature on causes of inequality is thinner and more contentious, but still, at least among the saner sort of economists, you expect not to find a lot of disagreement about whether inequality has increased since the 1970s or in how it is affected by policies like progressive taxation or universal education.

I have never seen anything that even vaguely resembles this from political science. Is that just because I am less familiar with the poly sci literature? Are there broadly accepted results on the political causes and consequences of economic inequality that a substantial majority of academic political scientists would accept? If not, why not? If so, how can I find ia review or summary of them, short or long?

Comment: The answer is "no" but finding authority supporting this answer would be trickier.